# Javascript get table value for specific cells

Tags: javascript, rows, cells

I have a the following JavaScript script:

```
<script>
    var tabel = document.getElementById('tabel');
    var order = document.getElementById('order');
    var payment = document.getElementById('payment');
    for(i=0;i<tabel.rows.length;i++){
        if(tabel.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML == "pending"){
            order.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }   else{
            order.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to make my table in `cells[1]` have red background when the value is "pending", and green background when the value is not "pending"

what should I do?

Comment: `tabel.rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = 'red'`, etc ? You know how to access the cell, you know how to set the background color. Looks like you already know everything to solve that issue on your own,

Comment: What is `order` element ?

Comment: Can you show us HTML code?

Comment: @FelixKling thank you, solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will make background color of 2nd cell to red or green depending on value of 2nd cell

```
var tabel = document.getElementById('tabel');
for(i=0;i<tabel.rows.length;i++){
    if(tabel.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML == "pending"){
        tabel.rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }   else{
      tabel.rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```